# Magento how to have different content (not in text_list) between pages?

Tags: php, magento

I have a few static pages I need to get into magento, the layout is basically as follows:

```
             [HOMEPAGE]

---------------------------------
|            <BODY>             |
|      -------------------      |
|      |    <HEADER>     |      |
|      -------------------      |
|      |      <NAV>      |      |
|      -------------------      |
|      |     | |         |      |
|      |  A  | |    M    |      |
|      |  S  | |    A    |      |
|      |  I  | |    I    |      |
|      |  D  | |    N    |      |
|      |  E  | |         |      |
|      |     | |         |      |
|      -------------------      |
|      |     <FORM>      |      |
|      -------------------      |
|      |    <BUTTONS>    |      |
|      -------------------      |
|      |    <FOOTER>     |      |
|      -------------------      |
|                               |
---------------------------------
```

The `main` area will hold the content entered into the admin cms which can vary page by page, which is perfect.

However I also need the content of the aside to change very slightly on certain static pages.  but i dont want to have t include the aside and the main in the wysiwyg editor in the admin.
How would I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When creating your CMS page, you have a "Design" tab where you can put xml.

You can use

```
 <remove name="blockname"/>
```

to remove your current block and then

```
 <block type="module/path_name" name="blockname" template="module/path_name.phtml" />
```

to add blocks here exemple :

```
<remove name="left.permanent.callout" />
<reference name="left">
<block type="core/template" name="mynewaside" template="aside/sometemplate.phtml" />
</reference>
```